# Selecting region information of product in northwind

Tags: sql, northwind

I want to to do following in northwind database:

**Display the Product Names of all products that were placed by customers in CA**
but I'm confused how to relate a **product** with **customer**.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my recollection you will need to join the `products` table to the `orders`, `orderDetails` and `customers` table to get the list of products ordered by the customers in `CA`:

```
select distinct p.ProductName
from customers c
inner join orders o
  on c.customerId = o.customerId
inner join orderDetails od
  on o.orderId = od.orderid
inner join products p
  on od.productid = p.productid
where c.Region = 'CA'
```

Or you can use `EXISTS`:

```
select p.ProductName
from products p
where exists (select od.productid
              from customers c
              inner join orders o
                on c.customerId = o.customerId
              inner join orderDetails od
                on o.orderId = od.orderid 
              where c.Region = 'CA'
                and p.productid = od.productid)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo of sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7dbe0/4)  of both queries.

Comment: *Recollection* .. with `Northwinds`?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk yup, old database. :)

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk not really, just wasting time!

Comment: We gotta find better things to do on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select o.pdt_name From orders o 
Where o.cust_no in 
 (Select c.cust_no From customers c Where c.state = 'CA')
order by o.pdt_name
```

Answer (score 0):

following did the job for me

```
Select distinct Products.ProductName From Products 
Where Products.ProductID in 
 (Select [Order Details].ProductID From [Order Details] Where [Order Details].OrderID in(select Orders.OrderID from Orders where Orders.CustomerID in(select Customers.CustomerID from Customers where Customers.Region='CA')))
 order by Products.ProductName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT PRD.PRODUCTNAME 
FROM CUSTOMERS AS CUST
INNER JOIN ORDERS AS ORD
ON CUST.CUSTOMERID=ORD.CUSTOMERID
INNER JOIN [ORDER DETAILS] AS ORDDETAILS
ON ORD.ORDERID=ORDDETAILS.ORDERID
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS AS PRD
ON ORDDETAILS.PRODUCTID=PRD.PRODUCTID
WHERE CUST.REGION='CA'
```

To list results in ascending order by product name add this to the end

```
ORDER BY PRD.PRODUCTNAME ASC
```